# Rewrite foreach statement to linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am still learning `LINQ` so bear with me :). My question, how to convert the following code into `LINQ`

```
int count = 0;

foreach (var item in settings.FavouritesSetting)
{
   if (item.FavouriteType != Constants.FavouriteType.Folder)
      count++;
}

return count.ToString();
```

Comment: How about installing ReSharper and inspect their suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var count = settings.FavouritesSetting.Count(i => i.FavouriteType != Constants.FavouriteType.Folder);

return count.ToString();
```

Comment: Does that take care the increment of `count`?

Comment: @PutraKg Sort of. `count` will contain the number of matches, i.e. end result. All the incrementings and comparisons are handled internally by `Count` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = (from item in settings.FavouritesSetting
            where item.FavouriteType != Constants.FavouriteType.Folder
            select item).Count();
return count.ToString();
```